# Conditional to check if an iframe is contained within a div in a variable with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

In need to check if an element ($myvar) contains an iframe. It could be nested several layers deep so I need to check all children.

This doesnt seem to work:

```
 if ( $myvar.children('iframe').length ) {
     console.log('has iframe');
 }
```

The element $myvar will change. Im not sure if there is an issue with the syntax of my code above, or if the issue is to do with $myvar updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `find` instead of `children`.

```
if ( $myvar.find('iframe').length ) {
```

- [`children`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) will only find immediate descendants.
- [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) will find all descendants - children, grandchildren etc.

---

See Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/b6v8kfsq/